# maven repositiory selecting unmentioned version for downloading the dependeny jar

Tags: maven

In my case, the pom entry is like this:

`<dependency>
<groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
<artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
</dependency>`

in my repository, there are 4 different versions of this jar varying from 5.8, 5.9, 5.14 and 5.15. But my system downloads 5.9 rather than 5.15.

can anyone explain this how and why? Is the dependency set in any other parent poms?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the jar in version "5.15" you can specify the version in your maven dependency like that :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
   <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
   <version>5.15</version>
</dependency>
```

In fact you should always put a version tag :

> When you depend on a plugin or a dependency, you can use the a version value of LATEST  or RELEASE. LATEST refers to the latest released or snapshot version of a particular artifact, the most recently deployed artifact in a particular repository. RELEASE refers to the last non-snapshot release in the repository. In general, it is not a best practice to design software which depends on a non-specific version of an artifact. If you are developing software, you might want to use RELEASE or LATEST as a convenience so that you don't have to update version numbers when a new release of a third-party library is released. When you release software, you should always make sure that your project depends on specific versions to reduce the chances of your build or your project being affected by a software release not under your control. Use LATEST and RELEASE with caution, if at all.

Comment: Never use RELEASE or LATEST anymore. See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4069. Simply use explicit versions. For plugins as well as for dependencies.

Comment: thing is i know about version tag. but even without this tag, my maven is downloading version 5.9. my question is, from where it is taking that version number. my colleague here is telling that it would have been downloaded through the parent pom's dependency's jar download.

Comment: Therer must be a parent which defines the version via dependencyManagement or it is defined by a transitive dependency. You should take a look via `mvn dependency:tree`.